# How do we say in English that pyramid is not skewed?

Tags: terminology

I would like to know if there is a term kind of "straight pyramid"? I mean, is there a word for a pyramid such that the line segment from the apex to the center of the base is perpendicular to the base.

Comment: The quality of mercy is not strained

Comment: @WillJagy That sounded pretty deep.

Comment: It droppeth as the gentle rain from heaven
Upon the place beneath. It is twice blessed:
It blesseth him that gives and him that takes.
'Tis mightiest in the mightiest. It becomes
The thronèd monarch better than his crown.

Comment: @WillJagy Merchant of Venice baby. Right on.

Comment: My father had this complicated joke about Mercy Hospital in Australia, which served a beverage with bits of herbs and nuts still in it, and named after a local animal; the conclusion was that The Koala Tea of Mercy is not strained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is *right*.

From [mathwords.com](http://www.mathwords.com/r/right_pyramid.htm):

> **right pyramid**: A pyramid that has its apex aligned directly above the center of the base.

Comment: (The term OP is looking for would then be "not right.")